# Get JSON data from external URL and display it in a div, but not work

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, getjson

Getting the error message "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.vateud.net/notams/warj.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access"

here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kt340aO4WTYPb5sjCUDj?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div"></div>

<script>

        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "http://api.vateud.net/notams/warj.json",
               processData: true,
               data: {},
               dataType: "json",
               error: function(){ alert("Error"); },
               success: function (data) {
                   $.each(data, function(i,item){

                    $("<p>").html(item.raw).appendTo(".div");

                  });
               }
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong i think. Use `$("p").html(item.raw).appendTo(".div");`

Comment: I think Problem with ajax . you can try with XMLHttpRequest in javascript

Comment: @Saik3037 — `$.ajax` is a wrapper around XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: "there will be an error message" — You managed to say that half a dozen times without ever telling us what the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of CORS, i.e cross origin request and you get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.vateud.net/notams/warj.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Read more about CORS here ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)
..

Also run the code sample below on your system and you will see any other errors in your console.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="div"></div>
    
    <script>
    
            $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "http://api.vateud.net/notams/warj.json",
                   processData: true,
                   data: {},
                   dataType: "json",
                   error: function(e){
                    console.log(e);                    
                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                       $.each(data, function(i,item){
                        $(".div").append('<p>'+item.raw+'</p>');
                      });
                   }
            });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: is there a way out to get the value of the url ?? and if you can provide sample code as a way out?

Comment: @januarsy the only way to get around with this is using JSONP or if you own the the api domain - you can pass the access-control-allow-origin headers..

Comment: @januarsy actually you can send a request to your PHP server and there hit a curl to the api to get the response and return it back to the page..